# spring-data-cassandra component/complex type denormalized mapping

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I'm trying to use spring-data-cassandra (1.1.2.RELEASE) and I'm running into an issue with the lack of embeddable type mapping in JPA parlance.

I have an entity class like this:

```
@Table
public class Customer {

    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private Address address;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

 }
```

and the embeddable Address class:

```
public class Address {

    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

}
```

My cassandra table:

```
create table customer ( 
    id uuid primary key, 
    name text, 
    address text, 
    city text, 
    state text, 
    zip text
);
```

I want the properties of Address to be mapped into the containing entity, I don't want a separate table for addresses. In JPA, I believe I'd use an @Embeddable annotation. Is there some similar construct in spring-data-cassandra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embeddable types are not yet supported by spring-data-cassandra. A feature request is available at [DATACASS-167](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-167).

The only possible part of an entity to embed is the primary key. If your primary key consists of multiple fields, you can externalize that fields into a separate class and use it afterwards with the `@PrimaryKey` annotation.

Comment.java

```
@Table("comments")
public class Comment {

    @PrimaryKey
    private CommentKey pk;

    private String text;
}
```

CommentKey.java

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
public class CommentKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7871651389236401141L;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String author;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 1)
    private String company;
}
```

HTH, Mark

Comment: Hey Greg, I found something else that might be interesting for you: Apache Cassandra through JPA/Hibernate: http://www.gregoriopalama.com/mongodb-on-wildfly-using-hibernate-ogm/, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/4.2/reference/en-US/html/ogm-cassandra.html#_configuring_cassandra HibernateOGM supports "Embedded objects are stored as additional columns in the owning Entitie’s table."